# How to search the dynamic minimum nomination amount?

Tags: minnominated

How to search the dynamic minimum nomination amount?

I use `this.api.query.staking.minNominatorBond` and it can not get the dynamic amount;
like this:

```js
const blockhash = await this.api.rpc.chain.getFinalizedHead()
const minNominatorBondValue = await this.api.query.staking.minNominatorBond.at(blockhash)
console.log(`minNominatorBond:${minNominatorBondValue.toNumber()}`)
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-scripts/blob/581b0e7ff146a3e87ce7f3a92e0ed12517a4350f/src/services/index.ts#L103) is how you calculate it, among all other staking metrics. To re-summarize it here:

```js
// a map from all nominators to their total stake.
const assignments = new Map();
const currentEra = (await api.query.staking.currentEra()).unwrap();
const stakers = await api.query.staking.erasStakers.entries(currentEra);

// populate the map
stakers
    .map(([x, y]) => x.others)
    .flat(1)
    .forEach((x) => {
        const nominator = x.who.toString();
        const amount = x.value;
        const val = assignments.get(nominator);
        // note that a nominator might have multiple validators, so we might need to add here.
        assignments.set(nominator, val ? amount.toBn().add(val) : amount.toBn());
    });

const nominatorStakes = Array.from(assignments);
nominatorStakes.sort((a, b) => a[1].cmp(b[1]));
const minActiveThreshold = nominatorStakes[0][1];

// 171.8319 DOT at era 859. 
console.log(api.createType('Balance', minActiveThreshold).toHuman())
```

`erasStakers` is the storage entry that is storing the final map of validators and their `Exposure`, which contains all of the active nominators as well. In essence, we are iterating over this data, and finding the smallest nominator.

`minNominatorBond` is a fixed storage item that is keeping the minimum to set a *nomination intention*. See [this staking update report](https://polkadot.network/blog/staking-update-february-2022/#staking-terminology) for more info.